# noUISlider: Linking Slider to an Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I'm using the noUiSlider to link a slider and an input as shown in the example on this page: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/linking-input-fields/

$("#slider").Link('lower').to($('#input'));

That works fine. However, if the value is negative (-1), is there a way I can convert to the absolute value (1) before passing to the input? I thought something like this:

```
$("#slider").Link('lower').to('#input',function(value){
    $(this).val(Math.abs(value));
});
```

That doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are the negative values allowed to be entered by the user? where is this value coming from? an <input> tag?

Comment: I'm using a vertical slider but there is no way to flip it or reverse the direction of it. The only way I could think do it was to use a range of 0 to -15.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of it? It'll be easier to point and solve your problem there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in fact reverse the direction of a slider; have a look at the [direction option](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/). 'rtl' applies to vertical sliders too, in the sense that is acts as 'bottom-to-top'.

With this option set, you'll be able to use a positive range from 0 to 15.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` function to solve this issue as you are trying to link input before slider loaded:

Example:

```
var slider = $('#slider-tooltip'),
    input = $('#input-with-keypress');
    setTimeout(function(){slider.Link('lower').to(input);},400);
```